# How to output placeholder image if no featured image set?

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

I am using the Multipostthumbnails plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-post-thumbnails/

And it has a certain naming convention to it. I know the usual way to output a placeholder if no featured image set, but not with their code?

I obviously want something like -

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ){   
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'news-large');
$image = $image[0];
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="" />';
} else {  
$image = get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/img/placeholders/placeholder.png'; 
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="" />';
}
```

But their existing code to show a featured image is -

```
if (class_exists( 'MultiPostThumbnails' )) : MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'header-image', NULL, 'header-image-full', array('class' => "custom-header-image") ); endif;
```

Just cannot see how to adjust this to fit my code at the top?

For Blog Pages -

Standard Code -

```
if (class_exists( 'MultiPostThumbnails' )) : MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail( 'page', 'header-image', get_option('page_for_posts'), 'header-image-full', array('class' => "custom-header-image") ); endif;
```

My attempt to try and show placeholder -

```
if ( class_exists( 'MultiPostThumbnails' ) ) { 
                        MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail( 'page', 'header-image',     get_option('page_for_posts'),
                            'header-image-full', 
                            array('class' => "custom-header-image") ); 

                        } else {  
                            $image = get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/img/placeholders/header_placeholder.png'; 
                            echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="" />';
                        }
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you're adding the code inside the loop of index.php or blog template file. You might be try this kind of things:

```
if ( class_exists( 'MultiPostThumbnails' ) && 
     ( MultiPostThumbnails::has_post_thumbnail( get_post_type(), 'header-image' , get_the_ID() ) ) ) { 
       MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'header-image', NULL, 
                          'header-image-full', 
                           array('class' => "custom-header-image") ); 

} else {  
  $image = get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/img/placeholders/placeholder.png'; 
  echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="" />';
}
```

Comment: Hi Chinmoy,

I have it inside header.php. Tried your code, but it just returns the placeholder image, even though the custom image is set?

thanks

Comment: Are you add the code inside the while loop? Please change this line `if ( has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ){ ` with `if ( has_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID() ) ){ `

Comment: It is outside of the loop, I have added new code to my original post so you can see the exact code I am using (including yours) but still only showing placeholder?

Comment: Ok. I just checked the plugin's code. `has_post_thumbnail()` is taking three parameters. But we are passing one parameter, for this reason if statement is not working. I edited the code again. Please see the code.

Comment: Tried the latest code. Still just returns the placeholder?

Comment: See my new code.

Comment: You got it!!! I had a feeling it needed taking out of the if has_post_thumbnail call. Thanks a million Chinmoy. I truly appreciate you taking the time to help me out.

thanks

Comment: are you added this `&& ( MultiPostThumbnails::has_post_thumbnail( get_post_type(), 'header-image' , get_the_ID() ) )` in if statement?

Answer (score 1):

Next time having a look at the docs might help ;)

```
MultiPostThumbnails::has_post_thumbnail(
    $post_type,
    $id,
    $post_id = null
)
```

Source: https://github.com/voceconnect/multi-post-thumbnails/wiki/Functions-and-Template-Tags#has_post_thumbnail

I guess you can make it from here. If not let us know.

Comment: Thanks kraftner ;) Just having trouble putting all my existing data into the function they mention?