# Possible to swap in a placeholder image globally for the_post_thumbnail_url if one doesn't exist?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I am working on a new theme for a site, but the majority of the posts don't have a featured image set. Throughout the new theme I am pulling in featured images using `the_post_thumbnail_url`. I am wondering if there is a function I can add to `functions.php` to override this url, globally, with a url to a placeholder image if there is no featured image assigned to the post.

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/157170/how-to-output-placeholder-image-if-no-featured-image-set

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the URL of the placeholder image, you sure can do it.

[`get_the_post_thumbnail_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/) function calls the [`wp_get_attachment_image_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_url/) function which in turns calls the
[`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) function to get the source of the post thumbnail. `wp_get_attachment_url()` returns the result from `wp_get_attachment_image_src` filter. So we can use that filter to modify the result if there is no image and the size is 'post-thumbnail'.

```
namespace StackExchange\WordPress;

function image_src( $image, $attachment_id, $size, $icon ) {
  $default = [
    'https://example.com/img.gif',
  ];
  return ( false === $image && 'post-thumbnail' === $size ) ? $default : $image;
}
\add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_src', __NAMESPACE__ . '\image_src', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems like what I'm looking for, however when I add this code to my functions.php I get the error: `Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script` If I move it to the top it breaks a bunch of other things. Any ideas?

Comment: If you're going to use namespaces, and you should, you should read and understand the [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) first. Otherwise, you can remove the namespace line and use a unique callback (e.g. 'wpse299844_image_src') for the filter instead. Make sure to remove the `__NAMESPACE__` too.

Comment: @NathanJohnson `return ... $url;` or `... $image;` ?

Comment: Once you're comfortable with this and have gotten far enough along, consider adding a theme option that allows you to quickly change out the default image without having to edit it via code.

Answer (score 2):

Well, depending on the thumbnails you have defined, you could do a check if the post *"has"* a thumbnail, display it; but if it doesn't, you can show a default image stored somewhere in your theme's image directory, like so:

```
// Other code to fetch the post
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail('slide');
}
else {
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/default-image.jpg" class="attachment-slide wp-post-image">
}
```

This is assuming you have already added the thumbnail `slide` like so:

```
add_image_size( 'slide', 500, 400, true ); // width=500, height=400
```

Hope this helps.